# Grails: Multiple row creation in single domain class

Tags: grails

Trying to create multiple entries in a single domain class via multi-row table:

[image]

Currently, when I create my entry it puts all of the entries, per field, in the same cell separated by commas:

Path: path1, path2, path3, ...

Having no luck (nor finding guidance) for containing these as unique entries; I'm not sure how to catch each row as a collection to feed it into the save method.

Comment: Where are you trying to "catch" it? In a controller? Then `def listOfValues = param.list('property')` might be the trick. You need to be more specific and give some code examples of what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to leverage the standard save method but iterate through the response and apply "save" to each instance